# View inconsistency when deleting tags

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, jobs

I just noticed a inconsistent and most likely wrong behavior while editing my Stack Overflow Careers profile.

Used browser: Google Chrome Version 40.0.2214.94 (64-bit)

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create or edit an `Certifications` entry, make sure that it contains at least one tag entry under `Technologies`.
2. Save the entry. The tag now shows up under the entry.
3. Click `edit` on the entry. Then click the little `x` on the tag to mark it for removal.
4. Click `Cancel` to abort editing. You return to the overview and the tag is still there.
5. Click `edit` again. The tag is not there, and there is no way to restore it unless you reload the page content some way. **Expected behavior:** The view content should be reloaded when clicking edit.

This could potentially lead to hazardous edits, when the user expects to reset the state via `Cancel->edit`, continues to edit and then submits an erroneus state to the server.

**Edit:** I just tried submitting the "broken" state with the missing tag, this does actually not cause the tag to be deleted after saving. Seems like the error is purely visual.

Comment: Unless you can prove it happens only in Chrome, there is no need for that tag.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, looking into it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been (finally!) fixed. Should be up with the next build.

Basically, our tag editor component wasn't getting notified when users cancelled the edit form. Since the inputs are reset through a form reset, the change events that the tag editor was listening to were never fired. I added a custom event that takes care of those shenanigans.

Thanks for your report <3

Comment: jQuery rulz! ;)